# Elasticsearch Rack Awarness

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm in ES 7.17.7 ES.

I have 6BareMetal(BM), each BM will have 4VirtualMachines(VM), each VM's having ES service running and all 5BM are in 3 Physical Racks.

Reason: I dont want Primary and Replica to reside on same BM as well as physically if a RACK is down it shud still have NO dataloss.

So my rack awarness setting will look like.

```
node.attr.zone: ${ZONE}
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: BM_ID,RACK_ID
```

Will this work?